# Pandas .apply lamda function returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I have a df of shape roughly (1000, 30) and need to compute a new column using a given funtion. Unfortunalty I can't share the data but, the function looks something like this:

```py
dof lookup_function(fn_value, fn_string):
    lookup_table = {"str_1": 14, "str_2": 5}
    return fn_value * lookup_table[fn_string]
    
def value_function(value_a, value_b, value_c, string_d):
    return 1000 * (lookup_function(value_a, string_d) - 0.5 * (lookup_function(value_b, string_d) + lookup_function(value_c, string_d)))

df["new_column"] = df.apply(lambda row: value_function(row["col_a", row["col_a"], row["col_a"], "str_1"), axis = 1)
```

There are no NaNs in any of the used columns and the string is for the moment even hard coded. The new column however still gets around 100 NaN values.
After I looked at the indexes I tried them myself like this with 2 being one of the returned indexes:

```py
print(value_function(df.at[2, "col_a", df.at[2, "col_a"], df.at[2, "col_a"], "str_1"))
```

and the function returns the expected value.

This results in me suspecting something goes wrong with the apply lambda function.

The average values in allcolumns are around `48.932261`
Their max being around twice that size.
Their min is positive as well.

I am aware my question is very vague, but I am hoping to find some kind person who has faced a similar problem in the past.

I tried generating random data to reproduce the problem but could not replicate the issue.

Edit:
I did find out that if I copy the df before I dont get NaNs.

```py
test_df = df.iloc[:]
test_df ["new_column"] = test_df .apply(lambda row: value_function(row["col_a", row["col_a"], row["col_a"], "str_1"), axis = 1)
```

Does Pandas remember in which indexes NaN are?

Comment: You can create a sample input and provide the expected output.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can not really. I did however find that, it has to be a weird issue, since when I only look at the first 10 rows, where the first couple of NaNs already appear and just run the function on the new df everything works fine.